# Is there a way to implement a Linear Regression with Hivemall?

Tags: hive, statistics, linear-regression, hiveql, bigdata

I'm new in this.
I don't know much about Hivemall.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement linear regression using Passive aggressive regression or AROW regression.
https://github.com/myui/hivemall/wiki/E2006-tfidf-regression-evaluation-(PA,-AROW)